# tweenMax.to not working in react componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I'm trying to use GreenStock `TweenMax` inside of react's `componentDidMount` method, but I see that the animation is not triggering (but the `onComplete` and `'onStart` methods fire just fine). I tried a few things based on a hunch and found that when I add a `setTimeout` for 100ms the animation plays. the hunch is that the element is not really ready at the time GreenStock is called.

I was under the impression that `componentDidMount` was similar to jquery's `$(document).ready()`

here is my simple code (without the settimeout written in coffee script:

```
componentDidMount: ->
  commentList = React.findDOMNode(@refs.commentList)
  console.log commentList
  TweenMax.to commentList, 1,{opacity: 0,onComplete :-> console.log 'TL called'}
```

the element `commentList` is being returned properly, but the animation is not playing (but the callbacks on the animation are)

is there something wrong with this code, or does someone know of issues between react and greenstock's tweenmax?

Comment: your right in that `componentDidMount` should give back a valid element at that point. If you were to do a `setTimeout(fn,0)`, does that work too?

Comment: you could try using **[`this.forceUpdate();`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate)** to re-render the component inside the `componentDidMount` method before making `TweenMax.to()` call. it is although not recommended, but could prove useful here instead of a `setTimeout`.

Comment: @mattclemens using `setTimeout(fn,0)` doesn't work. the time that works is `setTimeout(fn,1000)` which is making me think that there is some kind of lag in the app because `componentDidMount` should (logically) only be called when everything from that component is on the DOM

Comment: @TahirAhmed `this.forceUpdate( [function/callback] )` doesn't work nor does `this.setState()` with a callback. it's like the element isn't on the DOM when `componentDidMount` is called. I swear react has been trying my patience as of late

Comment: @zero: this is weird. can you put together a simple jsFiddle please depicting this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I had a unique key on the DOM element I was animating `require 'uuid'` `<div key={uuid()}></div>` (originally I was doing this with raw js and css3 which needed the element to be re-rendered) so removing it work